# How to include firewall in VM instance creation by DeploymentManager in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

my yaml template is as follows, I want to add firewall property to allow http traffic:

```
resources:

    - name: deployed-vm2222
      type: compute.v1.instance
      properties:
        zone: us-central1-f           
        machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/f1-micro
        disks:
        - deviceName: boot
          type: PERSISTENT
          boot: true
          autoDelete: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a firewall rule in your template as follow:

```
- name: allow-http-fw
  type: compute.v1.firewall
  properties:
    allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: 80
    sourceRanges: [ 0.0.0.0/0 ]
```

You can define the properties listed for the [firewall resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls).

Comment: Ideally you should include a tag in the firewall rule (instead of applying to all) and assign the network tag to the instance (using the tags.items[] field) to make sure the firewall rule applies to the instance

Comment: In addition to the `targetTags` as Patrick mentioned you should also add the `network` resource to the properties otherwise default network is used.
See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls#Firewall.FIELDS.network

Answer (score 16):

In the firewall, we use:

```
targetTags: ["http"]
```

Then, in the instance, we use:

```
tags:
    items: ["http"]
```

The complete file can be as shown:

```
resources:
- name: default-allow-http
  type: compute.v1.firewall
  properties:
    targetTags: ["http"]
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: ["80"]    
- name: vm-test
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: xxxx
    machineType: xxxx
    tags:
        items: ["http"]
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: xxxx
        sourceImage: xxxx
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: xxxx
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

Comment: In addition to the `targetTags` as Patrick mentioned you should also add the `network` resource to the properties otherwise default network is used.
See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls#Firewall.FIELDS.network

Comment: How do you create a Allow inbound HTTP traffic to tagged instances.
I tried doing something like IPProtocol: HTTP. But that threw me this error 
Invalid value for field 'resource.allowed[0].IPProtocol': 'HTTP"'

Answer (score 6):

A couple things to note when performing this action, make sure the instance is correctly tagged to enable the labelling to be applied. For example, tagging the instance, http-server or https-server ensure the firewall is aware it is processing public traffic.

Adding a firewall entry can be achieved in the following way.

```
resources:
  - name: instance
    type: xxxxxxxx
    properties:
      zone: us-east1-b
      tags:
        items: ["http-server", "tensorboard"]
  - name: default-allow-http
    type: compute.v1.firewall
    properties:
      network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/default
      targetTags: ["http-server"]
      sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: ["80"]
  - name: default-allow-tensorboard
    type: compute.v1.firewall
    properties:
      network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/default
      targetTags: ["tensorboard"]
      sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      allowed:
      - IPProtocol: TCP
        ports: ["6006"]
```

Comment: I got an error for using `tags: - http-server` : `message: '"/tags": domain: validation; keyword: type; message: instance does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: ["object"]; found: "array"'` what does it mean?

Comment: The tag definition has changed - updated example to reflect the correct usage of item/tags.

Answer (score 0):

@LundinCast is almost totally correct
`network:` under `properties` is missing.

It would be the same value as under `networkInterfaces:`